# ASP.NET Core MVC does not display new model value on view

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I am developing an ASP.NET Core MVC web app with TypeScript.

Below is my sample code

`Person.ts`:

```
 export interface IPerson {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Email: string;
    DOB: Date;
    Age: number;
}
```

`app.ts`:

```
import { IPerson } from '../typeScripts/Person';

window.onload = (event) => {
    //alert('page is fully loaded');
};

document.getElementById("btn_DOB").onclick = (event) => {
    let DOB = document.getElementById("txt_dob") as HTMLInputElement;
    if (DOB.value) {
        let diff = Math.abs(new Date(DOB.value).getTime() - new Date().getTime());
        let diffDays = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
        //alert(`Days Difference : ${diffDays}`);

        let _person = {} as IPerson;
        _person.FirstName = (document.getElementById('fname') as HTMLInputElement).value;
        _person.LastName = (document.getElementById('lname') as HTMLInputElement).value;
        _person.Email = (document.getElementById('txt_email') as HTMLInputElement).value;
        _person.DOB = new Date((document.getElementById('txt_dob') as HTMLInputElement).value);
        _person.Age = diffDays;

        fetch('/Home/Display/',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(_person)
            }
        )
            .then((Response) => {
                if (Response.ok) {
                    console.log(Response);
                    //return Response.json();
                }
            })
            .then((data) =>
            {
                //console.log(data)
            })
            .catch((Error) =>
            { console.log(Error) });
    }
    else {
        alert('First Select a Date')
    }
};
```

ASP.NET Core MVC action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Display([FromBody] Person _person)
{
    return View("Index", _person);
}
```

Razor view:

```
@model MVC_TS.Models.Person

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<form>
    <div class="container container-fluid">
        <div class="row g-3">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" aria-label="First name" id="fname">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" aria-label="Last name" id="lname">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2"></div>
        <div class="row g-3">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Of Birth" aria-label="DOB" id="txt_dob">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email ID" aria-label="Email" id="txt_email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2"></div>
        <div class="row g-3">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Click" id="btn_DOB" />
        </div>
        @if (Model.Age > 0)
        {
        lastname:  <input asp-for="LastName" />
            <p>@Model.FirstName;</p>
            <p>@Model.LastName;</p>
            <p>@Model.DOB;</p>
            <p>@Model.Age;</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>Nothing to show</p>
        }
    </div>
</form>

<script>var exports = {};</script>
<script type="module" src="~/js/app.js"></script>
```

It's all getting executed without any error or warning but when action method `Display` returns a view with model, it does not refresh page with new values. It always prints "Nothing to show".

```
@if (Model.Age > 0)
{
    lastname:  <input asp-for="LastName" />
        <p>@Model.FirstName;</p>
        <p>@Model.LastName;</p>
        <p>@Model.DOB;</p>
        <p>@Model.Age;</p>
}
else
{
    <p>Nothing to show</p>
}
```

Even though checked in view also by putting debugger there, `Age` is greater than zero, it still goes to those `<p>@Model.property</p>` lines, but in browser, it always displays "Nothing to show".

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here? Why is the view not displaying the new values?

Comment: You're doing an AJAX post instead of a form post. This will cause ASP to return the page to your javascript application. You probably want to render everything with JS instead of server sided, and then update the data with JS.

Comment: Any way to return view from IActionResult Instead of returning to js  ?

Comment: once you receive ajax response you can do `window.location.href = '/Controller/Action'`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @sairfan below approach solved this problem ,

```
window.location.href = '/Controller/Action'
```